# Please help me identify the SMD component

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount, gpu

I have two nVIDIA Quadro P5000 GPUs. This component got damaged in one of the GPU while I was removing it from the PC. Please help me to identify this SMD component so that I could purchase and solder onto the other GPU. 
Thank you[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is damaged on it? If it was ripped from the board, the solder points are most likely destroyed...

Comment: @MadHatter The package got a crack on the top. I was able to desolder the chip and solder pads are still there.

Comment: Being Q129, My assumption is it is a FET. If you unsoldered it, post image of bottom of package. Based on footprint, and assumption it is a FET, digikey could help you select one that would probably work...

Comment: @MadHatter I can't find the bottom of the package. But here is an image of the soldering pads.

Comment: yeah, looks like a MOSFET to me too.